# Postgres not leveraging index (jsonb) in recursive CTE

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a JsonB field in my table which holds hierarchical information.
MyTable( id uuid, indexes jsonb, content bytea)

Now if I create a CTE say

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy(pid, id, content) AS (
  --load first parents
  SELECT t.indexes ->> 'parentId' as pId, t.id, t.content FROM MyTable c
  JOIN MyTable t ON t.indexes ->> 'Id' = c.indexes ->> 'parentId' 
  WHERE c.Id = ANY('{..Some UUIDS}')
  UNION
  SELECT t.indexes ->> 'parentId' as pId, t.id, t.content
  FROM hierarchy h, MyTable t
  WHERE t.indexes ->> 'Id' = h.pid
) SELECT id, content from hierarchy
```

Now an example run of building a parent tree from 2 nodes within a table of 300K records takes approximately 10s.

Now if I create an index

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex ON MyTable
USING btree
((indexes ->> 'parentId')
```

This reduces the time to 4.5s.

I have found one method which is to wrap the SELECT t.indexes ->> 'parentId' in a function and then reference the function in the CTE and in the index.  This reduces the run-time massively to 0.01s.  Unfortunately though, the function has to be marked IMMUTABLE, and if the indexes value changes, or new rows are added, the index does not update.

Is there an option I have missed here to help the cte recognise the initial index, or do I have to set up triggers to rebuild the function index on a change?

The analysis for the json value index shows that the recusive part uses a merge join with an index scan and a sort. Where as with the immutable function index, there is a nested loop with a worktable scan and an index scan. No sort...

Index Function analysis of union part

```
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..371393.38 rows=8079403 width=1219) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=5)
                Output: (t_1.indexes ->> 'parentId'::text), t_1.id, t_1.content
                ->  WorkTable Scan on hierarchy h  (cost=0.00..179.80 rows=8990 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=5)
                      Output: h.pid, h.id, h.content
                ->  Index Scan using "MyFunctionIndex" on "TEST"."MyTable" t_1  (cost=0.42..30.06 rows=899 width=1219) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=5)
                      Output: t_1.id, t_1.content, t_1.indexes
                      Index Cond: ("TEST"."MyFunction"(t_1.id) = h.pid)
```

Index analysis of union part

```
          ->  Merge Join  (cost=770.60..290937.50 rows=8079403 width=1219) (actual time=360.467..360.476 rows=1 loops=5)
                Output: (t_1.indexes ->> 'parentId'::text), t_1.id, t_1.content
                Merge Cond: ((t_1.indexes ->> 'Id'::text) = h.pid)
                ->  Index Scan using "MyIndex" on "TEST"."MyTable" t_1  (cost=0.42..127680.55 rows=179742 width=1219) (actual time=0.019..288.168 rows=60478 loops=5)
                      Output: t_1.id, t_1.sourceid, t_1.content, t_1.indexes
                ->  Sort  (cost=770.18..792.65 rows=8990 width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=5)
                      Output: h.pid
                      Sort Key: h.pid
                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                      ->  WorkTable Scan on hierarchy h  (cost=0.00..179.80 rows=8990 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=5)
                            Output: h.pid
```

Comment: "*What I believe is happening*" - don't guess. Check the execution plan `explain (analyze, verbose) ...`. This would be much easier if you didn't obfuscate your relationship in a JSON column. Why can't you simply use a "usual" parent_id column instead? You could just add a colum `parent_id` and update that from a trigger when the JSON document is updated, then you can easily index that column (and use it in the CTE)

Comment: Good call! Ill append the analysis results

Comment: Having a custom column is one route for sure, but the users define the column names and the hierarchy relationships (can have more than one), hence the use of json.

Comment: I don't think a structure that changes for every row can ever be made efficient - at least not with a relational database. Not even with the JSON features Postgres offers. You probably want a graph database or something similar.

Comment: When we use the immutable function it is relatively efficient (particularly as we have max dataset sizes of ~500K) unfortunately graph databases arent much help when you cant guarantee consistency of joins, which we cannot, but yet the postgres CTE handles perfectly

Comment: I don't understand how you find the proper expression to index when "*the users define the column names and the hierarchy*". If you can find an index expression you can also use a computed column.

Comment: @JPullar are you sure that you need to sort the output in recursive CTE using `UNION`? Wouldn't `UNION ALL` also work for you and thus reduce the time?

Comment: We started with UNION ALL, but it was really super slow (timeout) due to the nature of building a hierarchy bottom up, not top down, you end up getting duplicate nodes which get their duplicate parents and the whole thing spirals out of control

Comment: Well as @a_horse_with_no_name this seems like a bad design to store such hierarchy within json. Even though user is defining names and relationships, you still know what it's gonna be when he does define it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hmmm, we might have to go the way of dynamically creating computed columns as a last resort.  Less elegant, more data duplication, so maybe someone has an answer?

Comment: I don't really understand the question per se and the problem with index. What does not leveraging index mean?

Comment: @ConsiderMe It was poorly chosen title I discovered after doing an analysis. I might recreate the question now I have a greater understanding

Comment: @ConsiderMe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658709/postgres-hierarchical-cte-unneccesarily-slow

Comment: Consider removing this question, since now there are "duplicates".