# Postgres syntax error on Create constraint trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, constraints, plpgsql

I need a trigger to cause a reindex (index is on an immutable function)
I define the function as

```
CREATE FUNCTION "TEST".triggerFuncTest()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  REINDEX INDEX "TEST"."MyIndex";
  RETURN NULL;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

with the trigger

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER triggerTest
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF indexes OR DELETE ON "TEST"."MyTable"
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "TEST".triggerFuncTest();
```

Which gives

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STATEMENT"
```

However the trigger will be created if I remove CONSTRAINT and DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, however this will cause an exception when triggered.

Comment: Why would you want to rebuild the index for each DML statement you are running? Are you aware that Postgres will automatically update the index? But a constraint trigger is the wrong thing in the first place, you want to a regular trigger (but still: this does not make any sense)

Comment: indexes on an immutable function dont get updated unfortunately

Comment: And why are you defining an index on an immutable function? That doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Also I tried a regular trigger, it throws an error as you cant change a tables index whilst its being accessed in the transaction

Comment: The reason for the index on the immutable function is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655425/postgres-not-leveraging-index-jsonb-in-recursive-cte